# Difference between wsgi.py and django.wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to serve my webpages using Apache and was wondering the difference between wsgi.py and django.wsgi.

There is documentation on both but I'm not sure which one I should implement. I am running on Django 1.4, Apache 2.2.2, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modwsgi/

Other questions:

1. Currently I'm implementing django.wsgi and have commands in that file. If I have to create wsgi.py, what should I put into the file? I can't find documentation on that.
2. Do I need to alter my virtualhost file? I am only running 1 website off my server.

Answer (score 2):

This files have same content but different names. In older django versions there is no `wsgi.py` file in project template and in docs that file was named `django.wsgi`. In recent versions wsgi.py file present in dir from start of project.

Name it like you want, if you havent one in your project. Just make sure that link to it in apache site conf is correct.

Comment: Did you mean to make sure that the path in my httpd.conf is correct? I didn't think I needed to change anything in apache.conf

Comment: I mean path to django.wsgi in apache site conf, WSGIScriptAlias

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference in the urls itself which you have posted. First url is from development documentation other is referring to older Django 1.2 Documentation.

In Earlier Version < 1.4 there was no wsgi.py file. But Since 1.4 it automatically creates wsgi.py file in your project directory.

Read the upgrade notes [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/#upgrading-from-django-1-4):

Comment: I am running off 1.4 and never had a wsgi.py file created for me. Would this be a concern? I did create a django.wsgi.

Comment: Probably you upgraded django later? Or may be python is referring to older version of django e.g. you have forgot to start your virtual environment and django was installed in system level python.